# Why is it not mandatory for function (used in select) to be used in Group by clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Just trying to think this through.

Assume below is SQL:

```
SELECT COUNTRY,RANDOM_NUMBER_FUNCTION(UNIQUE_ID),SUM(SOME_VALUE)
GROUP BY COUNTRY,UNIQUE_ID
```

Why is it acceptable to group by `UNIQUE_ID`?
Why is `RANDOM_NUMBER_FUNCTION(UNIQUE_ID)` grouping not mandatory since the function could return multiple values?

Comment: The function will only return a single value on one run, so it being idempotent is not relevant.

Comment: So it will not really group by the output (value) of the function but by the input to the function?

Comment: No, it's grouping by `UNIQUE_ID` already. For example, it's not different than returning `UNIQUE_ID` and another column computed as `UNIQUE_ID+1`.

Comment: I meant that - is it right to say that - the query groups on input value of the function rather than output of the function.

Comment: Neither, it's grouping on the columns you specified in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: In the example - UNIQUE_ID is specified in the group by clause

Comment: Yes, it is grouping on `COUNTRY` and `UNIQUE_ID`.

Comment: the function will return only one value, which will remain the same when doing the grouping. So there is no use in grouping on that

Comment: Ok - so the sum will be based on the country and unqiue_id value. although the the output contains a column having the result of the function?

Comment: Since you group by Country and unique_id, the outcome of the function will be just one value for every `country and unique_id` combination. So an extra grouping on that value, what difference would that make ?

Comment: Look at your resultset, can you find any 2 rows with the same value for `country and unique_id` combination ? You will not, that is what the `group by` does. And when you look at the values for the function, there can only be one value for every row, so what use would grouping by that still have

Comment: Based on what is it to be decided whether to use columnname vs function(columname) in the group by. I usually put whatever (other than aggregatev fields) is in the SELECT into the group by

Comment: The grouping is *not* required to give deterministic results; `SELECT CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(IntColumn) GROUP BY IntColumn` is also allowed, and gives a predictable number of rows, even if each contains random bytes. Even so, most functions in T-SQL are deterministic; certainly all user-defined functions are required to be (although you can work around this with tricks). In general, it will be more efficient to do `GROUP BY Column` rather than `GROUP BY Function(Column)` as the latter forces evaluation before grouping, but whether the results are what you want is another matter.